# I have OCD, is my 'ritual' considered prayer?

Tags: prayer, mental-illness

Please bear with me while I explain the background before I get to my questions.

I suffer from OCD (I also have a severe anxiety disorder, which may be relevant here).  About my OCD: I am compelled to do certain things a certain number of times.  Chief among them is I must knock upon wood after which I repeat a certain and very specific phrase which summarizes to something about keeping my family safe from harm (because of my anxiety disorder, my family's well-being is something I'm always *irrationally* worried about).

I grew up and was schooled Catholic.  However, I have since drifted from my original faith and now consider myself an atheist.  I don't believe in a higher power.  However, I also do not know why I have to do the things I do a certain number of times and am struggling to learn why.

This "ritual" I perform seems very similar to that which my late grandmother performed with her rosary and her daily prayers.

My questions are thus:  Are my compelled OCD actions considered prayer?  Have I (unconsciously) substituted the wood I must knock on for a rosary of sorts.

On the opposite side of the coin:  can my grandmother's behavior have been considered a form of OCD that she just wasn't aware of?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) I don't think an edit can fix it either.

Comment: Are you asking if Catholics would consider your OCD rituals to be prayer? If so, I think that's on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

There are very few issues on which "Christians" would come to (near) unanimous agreement about, but there is a high probability that you've found one here:

Could the OCD behaviours of an atheist be (legitimately) considered as prayer?

99.9% of Christians would say **No**.

cf. [Matthew 6:5-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%206%3A5-15&version=NIVhttps://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%206%3A5-15&version=NIV) for what actually does constitute Christian prayer.

Comment: Conversely, the grandmother's conscious, apparently freely performed, actions, would certainly be said at least by Catholics to constitute prayer.